# Bash read output?

Tags: bash, shell

Say I execute a bash script and the output is:

```
Test1: Some text...
Test2: Some text...
Test3: Some text...
```

How would I, in the same bash script, store the above output as one or more variables?

The ideal solution would be for it to be ready to be used in a conditional like so: (line one of output would be stored in `$ln1` etc.)

```
if [ $ln1 = "Test1: Some text..." ] ; then
```

Answer (score 45, accepted):

So you want

```
output=$(command)
while IFS= read -r line; do
    process "$line"
done <<< "$output"
```

See "Here strings" in the [Bash manual](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Redirections).

or [process substitution](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Process-Substitution)

```
while IFS= read -r line; do
    process "$line"
done < <(command)
```

---

Coming back to this after a few years, now I'd read the output of the command into an array:

```sh
readarray -t lines < <(command)
for line in "${lines[@]}"; do
    do-something-with "$line"
done
```

Comment: Is it possible to do something like this after the original command has already been run and stored in the output variable?

Comment: I don't understand your question: I demonstrate exactly that in the first piece of code.

Comment: Apologies, I realize I asked that in a way that made no sense. What I meant was, is it possible to capture output of commands that have already run? Ie: capture the last line of the terminal output, regardless of which command ran?

The closest thing I could find to this was to use the `script` command, see: [script.html](http://www-users.cs.umn.edu/~gini/1901-07s/files/script.html)

However, the `script` command includes everything the user sees, including `ESC` chars, etc, not just the stdout of previous commands.

Comment: Aside from re-running the command -- `output=$(!!)` -- I don't know how to programmatically capture the text that your terminal is displaying.

Comment: I am getting `process: command not found` when I run this on Mac.

Comment: @Sankalp use `echo` instead

Comment: how could I do the process substitution without waiting the process to end ?